# How to get rid of useEffect without changing the component's behavior?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

There is a trend saying that devs should get rid of useEffect as much as possible in React v18.

React documentation says

> An Effect lets you keep your component synchronized with some external
> system (like a chat service). External system means any piece of
> code that’s not controlled by React

However there are many situation where I can't find a way to remove the useEffect without making my component stop working as expected or look extremely ugly.

I.e. the case below:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface SearchBarProps {
  programType: "movies" | "series";
}

export function SearchBar({ programType }: SearchBarProps): JSX.Element {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string>("");
  const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState<number | null>();
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState<number>(0);

  /* 
  Restarts searchTerm and selectedYear when programType prop changes
  */
  useEffect(() => {
    searchTerm != "" && setSearchTerm("");
    typeof selectedYear == "number" && setSelectedYear(null);
  }, [programType]);

  const increase = () => {
    setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="search-bar">
      <p>{searchTerm}</p>
      <p>{selectedYear}</p>
      <span className="counter__output">{counter}</span>
      <div className="btn__container">
        <button onClick={increase}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there any way of removing the useEffect without affecting the component behavior?

Comment: can you except the `searchTerm`, `setSearchTerm`, `selectedYear`, `setSelectedYear` as props?

Comment: @Zachiah nop. searchTerm, setSearchTerm, selectedYear, setSelectedYear are part of SearchBar component.

Answer (score 1):

Im sorry, youre right, try calling it within the useEffect, like this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface SearchBarProps {
  programType: "movies" | "series";
}

export function SearchBar({ programType }: SearchBarProps): JSX.Element {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string>("");
  const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState<number | null>();
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState<number>(0);

  const handleProgramTypeChange = () => {
    setSearchTerm("");
    setSelectedYear(null);
  };

  const increase = () => {
    setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleProgramTypeChange();
  }, [programType]);

  return (
    <div className="search-bar">
      <p>{searchTerm}</p>
      <p>{selectedYear}</p>
      <span className="counter__output">{counter}</span>
      <div className="btn__container">
        <button onClick={increase}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But in that case you are using useEffect. The point was to get rid of useEffect if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code, I removed the useEffect and introduced a new function called handleProgramTypeChange. This function is called whenever the programType prop changes, and it directly sets the searchTerm to an empty string and selectedYear to null. This achieves the same behavior as the previous useEffect, but without using a separate effect hook.

```
import { useState } from "react";

interface SearchBarProps {
  programType: "movies" | "series";
}

export function SearchBar({ programType }: SearchBarProps): JSX.Element {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string>("");
  const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState<number | null>();
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState<number>(0);

  const handleProgramTypeChange = () => {
    setSearchTerm("");
    setSelectedYear(null);
  };

  const increase = () => {
    setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="search-bar">
      <p>{searchTerm}</p>
      <p>{selectedYear}</p>
      <span className="counter__output">{counter}</span>
      <div className="btn__container">
        <button onClick={increase}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But the function handleProgramTypeChange is never called. It will never run the setters.